# remove notification when app clear service

Tags: android, service

I have to problem when run service and notification.

I want to when user clear app, service stop and notification remove.
But i have not can to check service close to remove notification.
I check notification remove to close service success.
Service not call onTaskRemoved. Please help me, it is service for mp3 app.

```
package vn.top12.app;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ServiceInfo;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.StringDef;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.NotificationTarget;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ControlDispatcher;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultControlDispatcher;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import vn.top12.app.interfaces.IResultListener;
import vn.top12.app.models.Mp3Model;
import vn.top12.app.utils.CommonUtils;
import vn.top12.app.utils.YanNewsCommons;

import static vn.top12.app.MyReceiver.ID_NOTIFICATION;

/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p>
 * helper methods.
 */
public class MyIntentService
        extends IntentService {


    private SimpleExoPlayer mSimpleExoPlayer;
    private List<Mp3Model> mp3Models;
    private int mPositionCurrent;
    private ControlDispatcher controlDispatcher;

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
        mSimpleExoPlayer = YanNewsCommons.instance()
                                         .getSimpleExPlayer();
        mp3Models = new ArrayList<>();
        mPositionCurrent = 0;
        controlDispatcher = new DefaultControlDispatcher();
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("abc" + mSimpleExoPlayer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

        //unregister listeners
        //do any other cleanup if required
        NotificationManager
                manager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.cancel(ID_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        //stop service
        stopSelf();
    }

    /**
     * You should not override this method for your IntentService. Instead,
     * override {@link #onHandleIntent}, which the system calls when the IntentService
     * receives a start request.
     *
     * @param intent
     * @param flags
     * @param startId
     * @see Service#onStartCommand
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable final Intent intent,
                              final int flags,
                              final int startId) {
        System.out.println(">>>>"+flags);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,
                                    flags,
                                    startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println(">>>>> onDestroy");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("onHandleIntent");
        if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                // get data put to notification.
                String strModel = intent.getExtras()
                                        .getString(MyReceiver.KEY_PARAM_DATA_MODEL_PARSE_STR_RECEIVER);
                if (CommonUtils.isStringDataValid(strModel)) {
                    Mp3Model model = new Gson().fromJson(strModel,
                                                         Mp3Model.class);
                    handlerDataForNotification(model);
                } else {
                    //Parse error.
                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("error parse:");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void intListDataModelToService(List<Mp3Model> models,
                                          int position) {
        if (models == null) {
            return;
        }
        mp3Models = models;
        mPositionCurrent = position;

    }

    public void initListMp3ForPlayer() {
        if (mp3Models != null) {
            String[] strLinkMp3 =
                    new String[mp3Models.size()];
            for (int i =
                 0; i < mp3Models.size(); i++) {
                strLinkMp3[i] = mp3Models.get(i)
                                         .getUrlMp3();
            }
            initListMp3ToPlayer(strLinkMp3);
        }


    }

    public void seekTo(int windowIndex,
                       long positionMs) {
        if ((mSimpleExoPlayer != null) && (controlDispatcher != null)) {

            boolean dispatched = controlDispatcher.dispatchSeekTo(mSimpleExoPlayer,
                                                                  windowIndex,
                                                                  positionMs);
            if (!dispatched) {
                // The seek wasn't dispatched. If the progress bar was dragged by the user to perform the
                // seek then it'll now be in the wrong position. Trigger a progress update to snap it back.
                //  updateProgress();
                CommonUtils.showLogDebug("updateProgress not dispatched");
            }
        }

    }

    public void nextOrPreviousClicked(boolean isRightToLeft,
                                      Context context) {
        //seek to position new, and update model with current.
        if (mSimpleExoPlayer != null) {
            if (isRightToLeft) {
                if (mSimpleExoPlayer.getNextWindowIndex() >= 0) {
                    seekTo(mSimpleExoPlayer.getNextWindowIndex(),
                           0);
                }
            } else {
                if ((mSimpleExoPlayer.getPreviousWindowIndex() >= 0)) {
                    seekTo(mSimpleExoPlayer.getPreviousWindowIndex(),
                           0);

                }
            }
            // get current when next have finish.
            mPositionCurrent = mSimpleExoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex() <= 0 ?
                               0 :
                               mSimpleExoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            if ((mSimpleExoPlayer != null) && (mp3Models != null) && (mp3Models.size() > 0)) {
                updateUiToService(context,
                                  mp3Models.get(mPositionCurrent),
                                  MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_MP3_RECEIVER);
            }
            CommonUtils.showLogDebug("nextOrPreviousClicked" + mSimpleExoPlayer + "+" + mPositionCurrent);

        }
    }

    public void updatePlayOrPauseForPlayer(boolean isPlay,
                                           Context context) {
        if (mSimpleExoPlayer != null) {
            mSimpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(isPlay);
        }
        if ((mp3Models != null) && (mp3Models.size() > 0) && (mPositionCurrent <= mp3Models.size() - 1)) {
            updateUiToService(context,
                              mp3Models.get(mPositionCurrent),
                              isPlay ?
                              MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PLAY_MP3_RECEIVER :
                              MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PAUSE_MP3_RECEIVER);
        }
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("update player");
    }

    private void initListMp3ToPlayer(String... linkMp3) {
        if ((mSimpleExoPlayer != null)) {
            YanNewsCommons.instance()
                          .initializePlayer(mSimpleExoPlayer,
                                            new IResultListener<Boolean>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(final Boolean result) {
                                                    if (mSimpleExoPlayer != null) {
                                                        mSimpleExoPlayer.setVolume(10f);
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onFail(final String message) {
                                                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("message:" + message);

                                                }
                                            },
                                            linkMp3);
            CommonUtils.showLogDebug("initListMp3ToPlayer" + mSimpleExoPlayer);

        }

    }

    public void stopServiceAndClearFromOut(Context context) {
        if ((context == null)) {
            return;
        }
        if (mSimpleExoPlayer != null) {
            mSimpleExoPlayer.stop();
            mSimpleExoPlayer = null;
        }
        if (mp3Models != null) {
            mp3Models.clear();
            mp3Models = null;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                   MyIntentService.class);
        context.stopService(intent);
    }

    private void updateUiToService(Context context,
                                   Mp3Model model,
                                   MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER keyActionReceiver) {
        /*save list mp3 to receiver.
         * play or pause next.
         * */

        if ((context == null) || (model == null)) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                   MyIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(MyReceiver.KEY_PARAM_DATA_MODEL_PARSE_STR_RECEIVER,
                        new Gson().toJson(model));
        if (keyActionReceiver != null) {
            intent.setAction(keyActionReceiver.getValue());
        }
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("show data:");
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    void handlerDataForNotification(Mp3Model model) {
        if (model == null) {
            return;
        }
        //send pending
        PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                                                       1 /* Request code */,
                                                                       new Intent(this,
                                                                                  MyReceiver.class).setAction(MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_DELETE_RECEIVER.getValue()),
                                                                       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent previousPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                                                         3 /* Request code */,
                                                                         new Intent(this,
                                                                                    MyReceiver.class).setAction(MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue()),
                                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                                                     4 /* Request code */,
                                                                     new Intent(this,
                                                                                MyReceiver.class).setAction(MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_NEXT_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue()),
                                                                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent pauseOrPausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                                                             5 /* Request code */,
                                                                             new Intent(this,
                                                                                        MyReceiver.class).setAction(model.isPlay() ?
                                                                                                                    MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PLAY_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue() :
                                                                                                                    MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PAUSE_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue()),
                                                                             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent openViewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                                                         5 /* Request code */,
                                                                         new Intent(this,
                                                                                    MyReceiver.class).setAction(MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_OPEN_VIEW_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue()),
                                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String CHANNEL_ID = MyApplication.getInstance()
                                         .getPackageName();
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                               .getPackageName(),
                                                  R.layout.view_mp3_notification_small);

        remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivAlbumOfNotification,
                                       CommonUtils.getImageBitmapWithScaleDefault(CommonUtils.isStringDataValid(model.getThumbMp3()) ?
                                                                                  model.getThumbMp3() :
                                                                                  "https://static.zerochan.net/Fukuhara.Mikoto.full.2201488.png"));
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivPreviousOfNotification,
                                         R.drawable.ic_previous);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivNextOfNotification,
                                         R.drawable.ic_next);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivPlayOrPauseOfNotification,
                                         model.isPlay() ?
                                         R.drawable.ic_play :
                                         R.drawable.ic_pause);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitleOfNotification,
                                    CommonUtils.isStringDataValid(model.getTitleMp3()) ?
                                    model.getTitleMp3() :
                                    MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                 .getString(R.string.app_name));

        // set clicked.
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivPreviousOfNotification,
                                            previousPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivNextOfNotification,
                                            nextPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivPlayOrPauseOfNotification,
                                            pauseOrPausePendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rlParentNotification,
                                            openViewPendingIntent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                                                                            CHANNEL_ID)
                                                     .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                                                     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_headphone)
                                                     .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)//todo big content.
                                                     .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
                                                     .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                                                                                                R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                                                     .setOngoing(false)//ko cho xoa notification.
                                                     .setDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent)
                                                     .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
                                                     .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                                                                       CommonUtils.stripAccents(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                                                                             .getString(R.string.app_name)),
                                                                       NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);// set importance notification status
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            int idNotification = ID_NOTIFICATION;
            // avoid more notification set id default not change.
            notificationManager.notify(idNotification /* ID of notification */,
                                       builder.build());

        }

    }
}
```

My receiver

```
package vn.top12.app;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.util.List;

import vn.top12.app.models.Mp3Model;
import vn.top12.app.utils.CommonUtils;

public class MyReceiver
        extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String KEY_PARAM_LIST_DATA_MODEL_PARSE_STR_FROM_ACTIVITY = "mp3ListParse";

    public static String KEY_PARAM_DATA_MODEL_PARSE_STR_RECEIVER = "mp3ModelParse";
    public static String KEY_PARAM_POSITION_CURRENT_RECEIVER = "current";
    private static MyIntentService myIntentService;
    public static int ID_NOTIFICATION = 7;

    public enum KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER {
        // use name same with manifest
        KEY_ACTION_OPEN_VIEW_MP3_RECEIVER(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                       .getPackageName() + "_OPEN_L"),
        KEY_ACTION_NEXT_MP3_RECEIVER(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                  .getPackageName() + "_NEXT_L"),
        KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_MP3_RECEIVER(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                      .getPackageName() + "_PREVIOUS_L"),
        KEY_ACTION_PLAY_MP3_RECEIVER(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                  .getPackageName() + "_PLAY_L"),
        KEY_ACTION_PAUSE_MP3_RECEIVER(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                   .getPackageName() + "_PAUSE_L"),
        KEY_ACTION_SEND_DATA_FROM_ACTIVITY_MP3_RECEIVER(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                                     .getPackageName() + "_FROM_ACTIVITY_L"),
        KEY_ACTION_DELETE_RECEIVER(MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                .getPackageName() + "_DELETE_L");
        private String value;

        KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    public MyReceiver() {
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("myre" + myIntentService);
        if (myIntentService == null) {
            myIntentService = new MyIntentService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder peekService(final Context myContext,
                               final Intent service) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> peekService");
        return super.peekService(myContext,
                                 service);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,
                          Intent intent) {
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("abc" + isMyServiceRunning(MyIntentService.class,
                                                            context));

        if (intent != null) {
            CommonUtils.showLogDebug("intent" + intent.getAction() + "_" + intent.getExtras());
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                //get data.

                String strConvertMp3 = intent.getExtras()
                                             .getString(KEY_PARAM_LIST_DATA_MODEL_PARSE_STR_FROM_ACTIVITY);

                if (CommonUtils.isStringDataValid(strConvertMp3)) {
                    List<Mp3Model> mp3Models = new Gson().fromJson(strConvertMp3,
                                                                   new TypeToken<List<Mp3Model>>() {
                                                                   }.getType());
                    if (myIntentService != null) {
                        myIntentService.intListDataModelToService(mp3Models,
                                                                  intent.getExtras()
                                                                        .getInt(KEY_PARAM_POSITION_CURRENT_RECEIVER));

                    }

                }

            }
            if ((intent.getAction() != null)) {
                //handler
                if (intent.getAction()
                          .equals(KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_SEND_DATA_FROM_ACTIVITY_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue())) {
                    if (myIntentService != null) {
                        myIntentService.initListMp3ForPlayer();
                        myIntentService.updatePlayOrPauseForPlayer(true,
                                                                   context);
                    }

                } else if (intent.getAction()
                                 .equals(KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_NEXT_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue())) {
                    //todo next mp3.
                    if (myIntentService != null) {
                        myIntentService.nextOrPreviousClicked(true,
                                                              context);
                    }

                } else if (intent.getAction()
                                 .equals(KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue())) {
                    //todo previous
                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("previous");
                    if (myIntentService != null) {
                        myIntentService.nextOrPreviousClicked(false,
                                                              context);
                    }

                } else if (intent.getAction()
                                 .equals(KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PAUSE_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue())) {
                    //todo pause
                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("pause");
                    if (myIntentService != null) {
                        myIntentService.updatePlayOrPauseForPlayer(false,
                                                                   context);
                    }
                } else if (intent.getAction()
                                 .equals(KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_PLAY_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue())) {
                    //todo play. nhan status play se set up pause.
                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("play");
                    if (myIntentService != null) {
                        myIntentService.updatePlayOrPauseForPlayer(true,
                                                                   context);
                    }

                } else if (intent.getAction()
                                 .equals(KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_OPEN_VIEW_MP3_RECEIVER.getValue())) {
                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("open view");
                } else if (intent.getAction()
                                 .equals(KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_DELETE_RECEIVER.getValue())) {
                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("myIntentService" + myIntentService);
                    //put data next.
                    NotificationManager
                            manager =
                            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    if (manager != null) {
                        manager.cancel(ID_NOTIFICATION);
                    }
                    if (myIntentService != null) {
                        myIntentService.stopServiceAndClearFromOut(context);
                        myIntentService = null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,
                                       Context context) {
        ActivityManager
                manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if (serviceClass.getName()
                                .equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                    System.out.println(">>>>>truw");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my question with create service check service mp3 stop

> ```
> package vn.top12.app;
> ```
>
> import android.app.Service; import android.content.Intent; import
> android.content.pm.ServiceInfo; import android.os.IBinder;
>
> import vn.top12.app.activities.HomeNewActivity;
>
> public class MyStopMp3Service
>         extends Service {
>     public MyStopMp3Service() {
>     }
>
> `@Override
> public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
>     // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
>     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
> }
>
> /**
>  * This is called if the service is currently running and the user has
>  * removed a task that comes from the service's application.  If you have
>  * set {@link ServiceInfo#FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK}
>  * then you will not receive this callback; instead, the service will simply
>  * be stopped.
>  *
>  * @param rootIntent
>  *         The original root Intent that was used to launch
>  *         the task that is being removed.
>  */
> @Override
> public void onTaskRemoved(final Intent rootIntent) {
>     // close
>     sendBroadcast(new Intent(this,
>                              MyReceiver.class).setAction(MyReceiver.KEY_ACTION_RECEIVER.KEY_ACTION_DELETE_RECEIVER.getValue()));
>     stopSelf();
> } } </pre>`